# What is this style of art with blue and red shades called?

Tags: style

Does anybody know what this style of art called?

As I want to recreate the same style, is there any suggestion for techniques?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's based on something called [Anaglyph 3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_3D), but in a photo like this it's more for style and not actually creating 3D.

As for how to create it, there's [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/22289/23061) here on GD but also tons of off-site tutorials if you search the term.

Answer (score 0):

I call it colour shift, and achieve it by slightly shifting the RGB channels in Photoshop independently. Others may have a different name or method.